# R studio: Installation of tidyverse gets me non zero exit for "reprex" and "tinytex"

Tags: r, tinytex, reprex

Below is the message I get when I try to install tidyverse package and then I see tidyverse in the installed packages but I cannot use it ... what exactly is the issue here? I am using R version 3.6.0

```
* installing *source* package 'tinytex' ...
** package 'tinytex' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
vI[[j]]) :    namespace 'xfun' 0.22 is being loaded, but >= 0.23 is
required Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace ->
loadNamespace Execution halted ERROR: lazy loading failed for package
'tinytex'
* removing 'C:/Users/Owner/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/tinytex' Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘tinytex’ had
non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency 'tinytex' is not available for
package 'rmarkdown'
* removing 'C:/Users/Owner/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rmarkdown' Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘rmarkdown’
had non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency 'rmarkdown' is not
available for package 'reprex'
* removing 'C:/Users/Owner/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/reprex' Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘reprex’ had non-zero
exit status
```

Comment: When you see "'(something) (some version) is being loaded, but >= (some version) is required" that means you cannot update packages that are currently in use. Try restarting R and install the package before you load any other packages. Make sure you are not automatically loading any packages at start up. Restart R and run `install.packages("xfun")` to update that dependency. They try installing the rest.

Comment: I tried restarting the session and I tried re installing and the same problem occurs. from where can I ensure that there are no packages automatically loaded?

Comment: Well, when you start R you can run `sessionInfo()` to see if anything is attached. If stuff is being attached, you can check all the places listed in the `?Startup` help page where that loading might take place. The most common being an `.Rprofile` file in the current directory or your home directory.

Comment: This is what I get when I run `sessionInfo()`
_R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.0 tools_3.6.0_